# Weird error while using resetLocalAttrs

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-2.10, partialfunction

I have coded a macro which uses the resetLocalAttrs method of the (macro) context. After the macro has expanded, I get a weird error and I can't figure out what is happening. Firstly, I will introduce the problem. We have two primitives: the *state* (which I'll represent as a simple Int) and the *action*. The state represents the current state of the system, while the actions are responsible for modifying the state. The actions can be atomic or composed of atomic actions.

```
trait Action {
  def andNext(action: PartialFunction[Int, Int => Action]): AndNext = AndNext(this, action)
}
case class ActionId extends Action
case class AndNext(action: Action, and: PartialFunction[Int, Int => Action]) extends Action
```

As one can see in the code, the *AndNext* receives a partial function, because it could launch one action or another depending on the current state in that moment. An atomic action which is inside a composed action could require the preceding state as left by the preceding atomic action in the sequence, so I need to protect it with an *Int => Action*.

Let's test the code, using a dummy function to force the test to require a *Int => Action* parameter:

```
def f(lifted: Int => Action) = ???
f(implicit state => ActionId() andNext { case _ => implicit state => ActionId() })
```

It's OK, but I am working on a DSL, and it is too much verbose to write all those redundant *implicit state*, they must be hidden to make this code nice for DSL usage. Trying to reach the following cute invocation...

```
f(ActionId() andNext { case _ => ActionId() })
```

I have implemented a macro which turns the actions into protected actions (remember Int => Action):

```
implicit def lift[T](expr: T): Int => T = macro liftImpl[T]

def liftImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(expr: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[Int => T] = {
  import c.mirror._
  import c.universe._

  //reify(implicit state => expr.splice)
  reify(implicit state => c.Expr[T](c.resetLocalAttrs(expr.tree)).splice)
}
```

(*) Notice the **implicit** in the macro declaration, which converts the method in a view.

The former (and commented) reify works fine, but because of some limitations I have to use the reify which calls *resetLocalAttrs()* (you don't want to know, this question is becoming too long :). This reify fails with a weird error:

```
class Any is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Where am I trying to instance an Any? Why is the *reset* affecting the AST so much? I have used it many times and it was resetting the types and symbols nicely.

What's the better approach to find the problem? I have been working with showRaw enabling *types* and *ids* flags and it becomes quite hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial functions give rise to synthetic anonymous classes, and anonymous classes have known issues with typecheck-reset-retypechecking: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6187

```
17:04 ~/Projects/Kepler_macrosnippet00/sandbox (topic/macrosnippet00)$ scalac -Ymacro-debug-lite Test.scala 
performing macro expansion Macros.lift[ActionId](ActionId.apply()) at source-/Users/xeno_by/Projects/Kepler_macrosnippet00/sandbox/Test.scala,line-11,offset=449
((implicit state) => ActionId.apply())
Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(IMPLICIT | PARAM), newTermName("state"), TypeTree(), EmptyTree)), Apply(Select(Ident(ActionId), newTermName("apply")), List()))
performing macro expansion Macros.lift[AndNext](ActionId.apply().andNext(({
  @SerialVersionUID(0) final <synthetic> class $anonfun extends scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction[Int,Int => Action] with Serializable {
    def <init>(): anonymous class $anonfun = {
      $anonfun.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    final override def applyOrElse[A1 >: Nothing <: Int, B1 >: Int => Action <: Any](x$1: A1, default: A1 => B1): B1 = (x$1: A1 @unchecked) match {
      case _ => ((implicit state: Int) => ActionId.apply())
    };
    final def isDefinedAt(x$1: Int): Boolean = (x$1: Int @unchecked) match {
      case _ => true
    }
  };
  new anonymous class $anonfun() // an anonymous class created for a partial function
}: PartialFunction[Int,Int => Action]))) at source-/Users/xeno_by/Projects/Kepler_macrosnippet00/sandbox/Test.scala,line-11,offset=421
((implicit state) => ActionId.apply().andNext(({
  final <synthetic> class $anonfun extends scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction[Int,Int => Action] with Serializable {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    final override def applyOrElse[A1 <: Int, B1 >: Int => Action](x$1, default) = (x$1: <type ?>) match {
      case _ => ((implicit state: Int) => ActionId.apply())
    };
    final def isDefinedAt(x$1: Int): Boolean = (x$1: Int @unchecked) match {
      case _ => true
    }
  };
  new <type ?>() // <= the problem is here: the type has been irreversibly erased by resetLocalAttrs
}: PartialFunction[Int,Int => Action])))
```